# Errors after moving hosting service in PHP code

Tags: php, date, error-handling, proxy, server

I just recently changed my hosting service, and suddenly there are a few errors in my code, that wasn't there before on my old host service. How would I fix this:

```
$proxy = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

**error:**  Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

```
$date =  date('y-m-d');
```

**error:**  Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CST/-6.0/no DST' instead

^---I just want to get the date.

When I tried to use `date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');`, it printed out as just `1`. That's it.

Comment: Please include your old and new PHP versions.

Comment: @itsols Same version. 5.3

Answer (score 0):

1. what is available in `$_SERVER`, is set up dependent, therefore host dependent
2. 'US/Eastern' is deprecated use  `America/New_York` instead

Comment: to add to #1, never assume a key exists in the $_SERVER variable. It's better to check at runtime as WILL vary between hosts.

Comment: 1. What function should I use instead then?

Comment: @BenRowe Just tagging you.

Comment: @frosty $_SERVER is not a function so i'm not sure what your asking

Comment: Oh. Well, what should I use instead to get the proxy then?

Comment: simply check the key exists before you use it, like `$proxy = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : null;` If you don't, your code assumes it's always using a proxy.

Comment: Using $date = date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); and echoing it, got me 1, instead of the date.

Comment: @BenRowe Tagging you again.

Comment: you dont echo `date_default_timezone_set` that makes no sense

Comment: These are really separate questions. Check out this to find out how to get the current date: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dates-and-time-the-oop-way--net-35395

Comment: What? Shouldn't that work the same as the date() function? I just want to get the date!

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` does what it says on the tin, it sets the timezone, the **1** returned just says that it works, you then have to have to use the appropriate date function(s)